# Function with 2 parameters true/false eligibility

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have problem with mine exercise.
"/*In this Challenge we'll create a function that will whether a person is eligible to get a discount or not.
Only people over 50 who live in postal code 1234 are eligible to get a discount.
Create a function called check_eligibility that takes two parameters: age, and postalCode.
If the person is eligible for a discount return true. If the person is not eligible, the function has to return false.
(postal code is a number, not a string)*/"

only what i have to now is this :

```js
function check_eliglibility(age, postalCode) {
  var age = 50;
  var postalCode = 1234;
  if (age > 50)
    console.log("You have discount")
  return true
  else(age < 50)
  console.log("You don't have discount")
  return false;
}
```

im stuck because i don;t know how to join second condition in my function. Without it i can't figure it out what is next error in my code, i bet there is something wrong with it. Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 0):

Use && and || logic operators. Also you have wrong write of function condition 
function foo() {} `// You forget {}`

```
function check_eliglibility(age, postalCode) {
  if (age > 50 && postalCode === 1234) {
    console.log("You have discount")
    return true
  } 
  console.log("You don't have discount")
  return false
}

console.log(check_eliglibility(50, 1234))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function check_eligibility(age, postalCode) {
  if (age > 50 && postalCode == 1234) {
    console.log("You have discount")
    return true
  } else {
    console.log("You dont' have discount")
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i needed to. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You didn't use `{}`, try:

```
function check_eliglibility(age, postalCode){
    var age = 50;
    var postalCode= 1234;
    if (age > 50) {
        console.log("You have discount")
        return true
    }
    else if (age < 50) {
        console.log("You don't have discount")
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Why are you defining the variable age in the function? `var age = 50`
And the variable postalCode `var postalCode = 1234`

The variable postalCode isn't even used in the function.

Perhaps try:

```
function check_eliglibility(age){
    if (age > 50) {
        console.log("You have discount")
        return true
    }
    else if (age < 50) {
        console.log("You don't have discount")
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable age is already defined within the function parameters, so you call the function using `check_eliglibility("32")` (for example)

There is no point using the parameters, if you're going to define it within the function anyway...